# is it possible to detect/modify input from softkeyboard

Tags: android, android-input-method

I'm currently working on android service. One of its task is to read the input data entered by user (and also modify it) .

The only possible way that till now, I've figured out is to make a custom keyboard and write methods in that custom keyboard. I don't want this .

Is their any other method for it?

Thanks

Edit: I need this to work across multiple applications. So I don't think TextWatcher can help here.

Comment: AFAIK keyboard is being handeled by OS...not sure if it can be observed

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "service" in this context. Is this when typing into an `EditText`? If so, a `TextWatcher` might be an easier alternative. If you're trying to modify input to other applications, then it's different.

Comment: @matiash I want to read and modify input across multiple applications.

Comment: No.  That would be a pretty dramatic security risk to be able to read other apps' keyboard input like that.

Answer (score 0):

It can surely be observed by using an Accessibilityservice.

Check

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html

specially typeViewTextChanged and typeWindowContentChanged

This will not completly check all key hooks but you can check for changedtext in the focused window. With a little workaround you will be able to do what you want to do.